# Will a FAA 3rd class medical ever be issued to an airman on stimulants?

Tags: usa, faa, medical

While the FAA's Do Not Issue list includes all controlled substances (including Stimulants), I am wondering if there are ever exceptions made.

I would like to fly but I am currently on Concerta (methylphenidate), which would certainly disqualify me without any special issuances or approvals made. Is it possible to be approved for a class 3 (or higher) medical, while on stimulant medications?

Comment: Will it ever? We can't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these medications are disqualifying. The FAA requires that you stop them for 90 days before applying.

Assuming they were prescribed for an ADHD diagnosis, you will need to take a drug test to confirm that you are not medicated and then pass an intensive cognitive test. It's not a quick, easy, or cheap process, unfortunately.

If you were never diagnosed with ADHD, or were prescribed them for some other reason, you still will need to stop taking them. But not having an ADHD diagnosis on your record may make the process much easier. Carefully read *exactly* what you are required to disclose.